# Setting up winefish to compile sweave

Tags: editors, r, linux, sweave

The winefish latex editor has a "texbox" field in the preferences window, which tells it how to do various things, like PDFlatex for example.  There is something about regular expressions, a command to be run in shell, and various other parameters that I don't understand.  See the screenshot:

[image]

What parameters should I add to make it do sweave?  Note that these actions are indexed by the "F" keys, so pdflatex is F2.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of the purpose of some columns, but adding the following "TeXbox" (Winefish terminology) work for me:

`Sweave`   `.Rnw`   `1`   `2`   `3`   `R CMD Sweave '%B.Rnw' && R CMD pdflatex '%B.tex'`   `3`

This is equivalent to add this line in `~/.winefish/rcfile`:

```
outputbox: Sweave .Rnw :1:2:3:R CMD Sweave '%B.Rnw' &&  R CMD pdflatex '%B.tex':3:
```

This convert a edited `.Rnw` file in a `.tex` file and make the first PDF compilation, so you can see a preview with  <kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

Note that often you will need more than one `pdflatex` and auxiliar programs run to solve cross-references, make the index, etc., so probably you may want a more elaborate command.

BTW, do yo know `RStudio`?

Comment: This seems to work, but let me play with it some.  And I really dislike RStudio -- you can't undock the windows, which is a total dealbreaker for me.  RGedit 4 lyfe